# What is the need and how to use SideEffect API in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am learning jetpack-compose and I want to understand the need for side-effect API in the android jetpack-compose library.

I have learned little about the launch effect and written code with and without it to handle out-of-composable scope work.
For both the cases the code works the same way.

1. Without LauchEffect

```
Row {
        Text(text = "Hello World")
        Button(onClick = {
            state = !state
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }){
            Text(text = "Click me")
        }
    }
```

2. With LauchEffect

```
Row {
        Text(text = "Hello World")
        Button(onClick = {
            state = !state
        }){
            Text(text = "Click me")
        }
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = state, block = {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
    }
```

Please help me understand the side-effect API and why we need a robust example

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects

> A side-effect is a change to the state of the app that happens outside the scope of a composable function.

`onClick = { }` <<< this lambda is not a composable (it is outside the scope of the function).

It doesn't get recomposed.

So your onClick is a side-effect, both examples are the same (one is easier to read).

Answer (score 0):

In your example there is not much difference. But `LaunchedEffect` allows us to react to events coming to our composable from outside. For example, lets say our composable have a `connected: Boolean` parameter to indicate connection status. Now we can have a `LaunchedEffect(connected)` that will react to changes in connection status. Another important feature of `LaunchedEffect` is that it will cancel previous coroutine before launching a new one, so we don't have to worry about launching multiple coroutines performing the same task.